# Why is my breadth first search algorithm so slow?

Tags: python, algorithm, search, binary-search-tree, breadth-first-search

I am implementing a breadth first search algorithm in Python to solve the 8 puzzle game http://mypuzzle.org/sliding. I was told that this algorithm should not take more than a few minutes to run, but its been running for over an hour. Is there something wrong with my algorithm or implementation? Or was the person who told me this could run in a few minutes mistaken?

Here is my code:

Edit: You can run this in the command line with `python driver.py bfs <nine numbers separated by commas>` I'm using python driver.py bfs 9,3,7,5,0,6,4,1,2

driver.py

```
import sys
from SearchAlgorithms import bfs#, dfs, ast, ida

if __name__=='__main__':
    board = [int(s) for s in sys.argv[2].split(',')]
    if(sys.argv[1]=='bfs'):
        output = bfs(board)
    elif(sys.argv[1]=='dfs'):
        output = bfs(board)
    elif(sys.argv[1]=='ast'):
        output = bfs(board)
    elif(sys.argv[1]=='ida'):
        output = bfs(board)
    else:
        raise IOError
    print(output)
```

SearchAlgorithms.py

```
from queue import Queue
import math
import time
import copy

class Board:
    def __init__(self, data, path=[]):
        self.data = data
        self.path = path
    def neighbors(self):
        neighbors = []
        board_width = int(math.sqrt(len(self.data)))
        if self.data.index(0) - board_width >= 0:
            new_data = copy.deepcopy(self.data)
            new_data[self.data.index(0)], new_data[self.data.index(0) - board_width] = self.data[self.data.index(0) - board_width], 0
            neighbors.append(Board(new_data, self.path + ['Up']))
        if self.data.index(0) + board_width < len(self.data):
            new_data = copy.deepcopy(self.data)
            new_data[self.data.index(0)], new_data[self.data.index(0) + board_width] = self.data[self.data.index(0) + board_width], 0
            neighbors.append(Board(new_data, self.path + ['Down']))  
        if self.data.index(0) - 1 >= 0:
            new_data = copy.deepcopy(self.data)
            new_data[self.data.index(0)], new_data[self.data.index(0) - 1] = self.data[self.data.index(0) - 1], 0
            neighbors.append(Board(new_data, self.path + ['Left']))
        if self.data.index(0) + 1 < len(self.data):
            new_data = copy.deepcopy(self.data)
            new_data[self.data.index(0)], new_data[self.data.index(0) + 1] = self.data[self.data.index(0) + 1], 0
            neighbors.append(Board(new_data, self.path + ['Right']))
        return neighbors

def bfs(board):
    before = time.time()
    goal = sorted(board)
    graph = Board(board)
    frontier = [graph]
    explored = set()
    count = 0
    while frontier:
        count +=1
        if count % 100 == 0:
            print(count)
        state = frontier.pop(0)
        explored.add(state)

        if state.data == goal:
            return {'path_to_goal': reversed(state.path),
                    'cost_of_path': len(state.path),
                    'nodes_expanded': len(explored),
                    'fringe_size': len(frontier),
                    'running_time': time.time() - before
                                             }
        for neighbor in state.neighbors():
            if neighbor not in set().union(frontier, explored) :
                frontier.append(neighbor)
    return False
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tried debugging with the pdb? (See [pdb for python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) or [pdb for python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) depending on your python version.)

Comment: I see a [mutable default argument](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/) in `Board.__init__`.

Comment: You're also using a lot of slow `index` and `pop(0)` calls.

Comment: Those assignments to `new_data[thing], new_data[other_thing]` are more error-prone than they might seem, because `other_thing` is evaluated after the first assignment. I don't think it's causing issues here, but still, be wary when doing that.

Comment: Were you actually given a solvable input? Not all inputs have a solution.

Comment: You might also take this to CodeReview.StackExchange.com.  I haven't flagged this for "wrong site" closure, because you're on the borderline -- functional failure is also a problem.

Comment: The given code fails to run: either re-code the driver for a particular input, or give us the command line to do it.  Don't make us read your code to reverse-engineer the input format.

Comment: Shouldn't take more than a few **seconds** (maybe not even one second).

Comment: Your `Board` has no `__eq__` or `__hash__`, so you're adding every state to `frontier` and then `explored`, regardless of whether it's already been explored. This is a really big problem. (If you add `__eq__` and `__hash__`, you should think carefully about whether `path` should be involved in those methods.)

Comment: @user2357112 I only add the state to the frontier if its not in the union between frontier and explored, and I only add the state to explored if its been added to frontier

Comment: @MatthewDrill: But `neighbor` is never found in `set().union(frontier, explored)`, because you never defined how `==` or `hash` handle your objects.

Comment: (Also, making that `set().union` call every time is expensive.)